# Why CSS transition won't render correctly in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-transitions

I made a simple container component. On toggle button press open the container and when pressed again close the container. I made an transition in CSS to animate it(grow from 0px to 200px for now).
The problem is that my transition doesn't work(show). I do not remove the component, just update it. I have no map functions on the container.

```js
const ToggleButton = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={classes.button} {...props}>
      {props.toggle ? (
        <ToggleLess className={classes.button_icon} />
      ) : (
        <ToggleMore className={classes.button_icon} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const ToggleContainer = () => {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => {
    setToggle(!toggle);
    console.log(toggle);
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
            <div className={`contents ${toggle ? "on" : ""}`}>
                <p>Hy</p>
            </div>
      <ToggleButton toggle={toggle && true} onClick={handleClick} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ToggleContainer;
```

```css
.contents {
  max-height: 0px;
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
    
}
.contents.on{
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

Note: the  and  are just a svg files imported.

I documented different stack answers but nothing seem to work.

Comment: `max-height` !== `min-height`

Comment: @Thomas The container is shrinking and growing but it is not animating.*** Edit you we're right!

Answer (score 0):

```
.contents{
    min-height: 0px;
    transition: all 1s ease-in;
    &.on{
        min-height: 200px;
    }
}
```

I had to set all not min-height, to be more specific what @Thomas commented, min-height!=max-height.